# Extracting the callback function name from an HTML element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an element on a page like this:

```
<input id="qty1" type="number" class="number" name="123" onchange="updatedQtyItemListBuild('sku2010109');">
```

I'm trying to grab the actual text inside the onchange call in order to parse out the sku value.  When I use jQuery's attr("onchange"), I get a reference to the function, but not the text itself.  I can't change the page at all to add it elsewhere.

Am I missing something here or is there a way to do this with standard script?

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply getting the attribute returns the string literal

```
document.getElementById('qty1').getAttribute('onchange'); //updatedQtyItemListBuild('sku2010109');
```

What exactly are you having a problem with?

Comment: That's exactly it - I was trying to make use of jQuery and only getting the function object in return, not the literal, thank-you